# Getting a bunch of divs to line up correctly inside a div that is floated right

Tags: html, css

I think it is best described by looking at an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kV9yn/16/

That is my code (simplified) the problem is that the rectangle divs on the right div don't line up correctly. What I want is for them to line up from left to right, and then carry over onto the second line when they go past the edge of the div:

**Intended look:**

```
   ._______________________________________________________________________.
   |                                                                       |
   |                              Title                                    |
   |                                                                       |
   |  blah blah blah blah blah blah                                        |
   |                                                                       |
   | Ingredient: [                ]       [block] [block] [block] [block]  |
   |                                      [block] [block] ...              |
   |                                                                       |
   |_______________________________________________________________________|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
.ingredient
{
    display:block;
    ...
```

To:

```
.ingredient
{
    display:inline-block;
    ...
```

And you're all set. The name of the property is pretty self-explanatory.

---

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kV9yn/12/.

Comment: Wow that was simple >< Thanks!

Comment: No problem. That's a pretty cool looking site design you're working with.

Comment: Thanks! The full design looks even cooler, but i stripped out a lot of the mark up / css in my fiddle to make it easier to debug. =]

Answer (score 0):

HOw about something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The divs?</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        body {
            margin: auto;
            width: 600px;
        }
        #blocks {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
        }
        .leftFloat {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 1em;
            width: 18%;
        }
        fieldset {
            border: none;
            float: left;
            width: 40%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="ingredient">Ingredient:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ingredient" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="blocks">
        <div class="leftFloat">
            [block]</div>
        <div class="leftFloat">
            [block]</div>
        <div class="leftFloat">
            [block]</div>
        <div class="leftFloat">
            [block]</div>
        <div class="leftFloat">
            [block]</div>
        <div class="leftFloat">
            [block]</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```